# When is it worth to sort an array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, big-o

Years ago, in a job interview, I was asked: When is it worth to sort an array? I remember not being able to answer properly, recently I did an algorithm course, and I come to the conclusion that providing a more "academical" response would have probably got me that job... anyway, it is not possible to fix the past, so far I am trying to formally answer it to myself, currently, this is where I am:

Given an array, the time to search will be

- O(n) if not sorted
- O(log(n)) if sorted

Considering that quick sort sorts in O(n*log(n))

When is it worth to sort an array? It would of course depend on the number of times we are going to search the array.

- Cost of searching x times in sorted array = O(n*log(n)) + [O(log(n)) * x]
- Cost of searching x times in unsorted array = O(n) * x

What would be the value of x?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question

Comment: There is another hidden bonus to sorted data. Your code may actually run faster due to branch prediction of modern processors.

Comment: @TomHeard I understand, but trust me is not, actually I finished university years ago. The problem for me is that I have wondered this question some times, and I always get lost with big-o notation operations.

Comment: Landau notation won't help you in this case. Suddenly, the constants and the actual runtime __is__ important.

Comment: @Johannes that is an interesting point

Comment: This seems like algebra, although big-o notation does hide a lot of the constants that you will need for the algebraic check

Comment: You could always try `n*log(n) + (x*log(n)) = n*x` and solve for x, that will be where the cost is equal. But again this won't be quite accurate, as it ignores constants.

Comment: @TomHeard : As far as I understand, the only constant would be the O(n*log(n)) that is needed for the first sorting, amd I wrong?

Comment: You can say that it becomes worthwhile when the number of searches approaches the number of entries, but the exact crossing point can easily be an order of magnitude one direction or the other.  The other thing you can say it that it's worthwhile when the search is time-sensitive and the prep is not.

Comment: It is also dependant on `n` not just `x`

Comment: No when I say it ignores constants, I mean that big-o notation will strip any constant not relative to n. You can't simply plug in an `n` value and expect the runtime as the answer. For example one algorithm on O(n*log(n)) can have a completely different runtime compared to another algorithm of O(n*log(n)) even if they have the same value for n.

Comment: `x` will differ depending on the programming language, implementation and machine. This is really just something you need to benchmark.

Comment: @Dunkeling Is it not possible to generalize it anyway?

Comment: Sometimes you don't know ahead of time how much you will be using the array. In this case a good rule of thumb is to sort when you have spent as much extra time searching as it would cost to sort. This is a special case of the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ski_rental_problem, which could be applied to many questions about when to invest time or money in making life easier.

Comment: So if we are ignoring constants of your sorting algorithm (which you really shouldn't). If `x > nlog(n) / (n - log(n))`, you should sort first.

Comment: This is a simplification of `n*log(n) + (x*log(n)) < n*x` which is solving for when `n*x` (non-sorted search x times) is greater than `n*log(n) + (x*log(n))` (sorting then searching x times).

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would answer, that it is worth sorting an array if any of the following is true:

- we plan to often ask for the biggest value in the array (cut cost from O(n) to O(1)),
- we plan to often ask for the smallest value in the array (cut cost from O(n) to O(1)),
- we will often seek for a given value in the array (cut cost from O(n) to O(log(n)).

If it is possible to sort the array in O(n) (for ex., the data fulfills the criteria for counting sort) we would start gaining from search operation (so the total time, including time necessary for sorting, will be smaller than time taken by searching in an unsorted array) after k operations, where **k = constantOfSortingOperation / (n/log(n))** (time it  took to sort the array divided by gain from searching the sorter array).

If we sort the array in O(nlogn), using for ex. HeapSort or QuickSort (where the constant hidden in big-O notation is small) we would start gaining from search operation after **k = (constant*nlogn)/ (n/logn)**. constant/nlogn is basically how many Times could we search the unsorted array if we spend the time not on sorting, but on searching. n/logn is how much we gain from a single search in a sorter array compared to search in an unsorted array. So if we consider our constant to be small (much smaller than n) the time after we start gaining (= x, more or less) would be approximately **n*logn * logn / n = (log(n))^2.**

If we include calculations of gains from getting the biggest/smallest value, we start gaining from sorting an array much faster.